# how to deserialize this JWT into a class with json.net

Tags: json.net, jwt

I have a JWT with the following content:

```
{
    "jti":"b17373d5-2755-435b-916a-9b87c9354427",
    "resource_access":"{"test-app":{"roles":["anonymous"]}}"
}
```

the issue is the *resource_access* part:

it it looks like:

```
dictionary<string, dictionary<string, list<string>>>
```

The problem is that json.net gives this error:

```
 Error converting value "{" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]]'. Path 'resource_access', line 1, position 335. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]].
```

The json validator at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ lets this json pass as properly formatted, but I'm not sure it follows the standard to start with.

So, my question is: can this be deserialized without making a custom deserializer?

Comment: I just posted the JSON in your question to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and I got a lot of errors including  `Expecting comma, colon or }, not string.`, `Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.` and `Extra closing }`.  That's because the JSON isn't well-formed: the double-quotes in the `"resource_access"` string should be escaped like so: `"{\"test-app\":{\"roles\":[\"anonymous\"]}}"`.  Json.NET well definitely throw an exception on such not-well-formed JSON.

Comment: weird, when I paste it, it passes (check https://imgur.com/CsO7Nvp), ok, so I need to make sure the strings are escaped properly. thanks!